# NVIDIA driver problem after migration to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia

This question is in the following by [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186409/can-i-combine-free-space-unmounted-partition-ntfs-to-ext4-linux-partition/1186474?noredirect=1#comment1983978_1186474).
Before with Linux Mint **LMDE** update, I had an **Nouveau** error, sticking in login loop, no sound driver found and no Ethernet icon in network manger which i think was from my NVIDIA driver incompatibility with Linux new version for **nouveau** part problem, hence my switch to Ubuntu 18.04.

I tried adding **nomdeset** in grub file with pressing E button at first boot option of my dual boot (Win & Linux) and with pressing **ALt+Ctrl+F3** i could go to terminal environment and run `sudo startx` to have access to root, i have also tried to change my /`home` permission changing as said [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) and [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-ubuntu-login-loop/) ,but it don't solved my problem, i have also tried `sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get upgrade` by adding

so i found better community via Ubuntu, now i installed Ubuntu by [this instruction](https://itsfoss.com/replace-linux-from-dual-boot/) and some of my system info's are here:

```
root@so-notebook:~# lshw -c display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:129 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM108M [GeForce 920MX]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:131 memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
root@so-notebook:~#
```

Like this (Excuses me because of low quality photo which i could not take screen shut from my Linux!!!):

[image]

It also have found `nvidia-driver-440` as `recommended` as you could see here:

```
root@so-notebook:~# sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:03:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd0000134Fsv000017AAsd000039F1bc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM108M [GeForce 920MX]
driver   : nvidia-driver-410 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-440 - third-party free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-430 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-415 - third-party free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.1 ==
modalias : usb:v0BDAp0821d0200dcE0dsc01dp01icE0isc01ip01in01
vendor   : Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
driver   : rtl8812au-dkms - distro free
```

So in software Updates have this configuration:

[image]

So as you can see it have been installed but `nvidia-smi` said:

```
root@so-notebook:~# nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

So i will try reboot, but according my previous experiences i guess it don't working and i must reinstall NVIDIA driver with `sudo apt purge nvidia*`.

So could i only run my Linux with Intel driver?
why many drivers corrupted in Linux Ubuntu also  like Ethernet,sound and login loop ?!!!

***Update:***

So as i thought it don't worked with `nvidia-driver-440` which recommended by Ubuntu Auto driver instillation !!! i have used `sudo apt purge nvidia*` and i could run `'sudo startx` but before of that when i run that command it hang after some codes which don't show any error message.

According **@Michal_Przybylowicz** Comment the output of  `grep -i "nvidia" /var/log/Xorg.0.log` when i deleted the NVIDIA driver is:

```
root@so-notebook:~# grep -i "nvidia" /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[   125.232] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[   125.232] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[   125.232] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[   125.232] (II) Unloading nvidia
[   125.232] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[   125.233] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[   125.272] (--) NOUVEAU(G0): Chipset: "NVIDIA NV118"
```

Comment: What is the output of command `grep -i "nvidia" /var/log/Xorg.0.log` ?

Comment: Now i deleted the NVIDIA but i updated the questions you asked when it is deleted.

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: I sloved it and firget the suolution, but know nvidia 390 is working for me and also preferred to disable nvidia, and use only ontel graphic card. You coyld try [this](https://tecadmin.net/install-latest-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu/) instructions with nvidia 390 .